# Xcode incorrectly "recognizing" iOS Simulator as actual Device

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I'm using the camera and want to check if I'm using the **iOS Simulator or an actual Device**, so I put this statement in my code:

```
    #if IOS_SIMULATOR
        print("It's an iOS Simulator")
    #else
        print("It's a device")
    #endif
```

However when I'm running the device in the iOS Simulator it actually prints out "It's a device".

Which is the **opposite**.  Is there some other Xcode setting or flag I can check for this?

It seems as though I would have something selected saying "Even if it's the Simulator always run as if it's a device" you know?

Comment: Why not put code in to simply check if a camera exists? Seems like the best way to code for it.

Comment: @dfd good point, that seems like a much better way.  I guess I was thinking that if it was the Simulator I needed the Camera Photo Library, and maybe I was mixing Camera and Photo Library as one when they are separate.

Comment: I know old - as in very old - iPads had no cameras and I believe iPod touch devices may not. I have code that uses UIImagePickerController to check for a camera and can post it if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting IOS_SIMULATOR from, but it's certainly not from Apple.  I suggest you use Apple's APIs for doing this.  Eg:

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>

#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
...
#else
...
#endif
```